# WHEA-Logger Cache Hierarchy Error in Win8.1

Tags: motherboard, windows-error-reporting

I have a 3 week old machine built by QuietPC http://www.quietpc.com/sys-serenity-pro-gamer

Gigabyte Z97X-UD3H with an Intel4790K

I'm getting *WHEA-Logger* warning errors on Win8.1 sometimes every minute

No BSOD's.

All default settings on the motherboard, latest BIOS - F7 (have updated to F8b which made no difference).  All drivers up to date

WHEA Errors started as soon as I put on Win8.1 and there was no overclocking then, and none now.

More detail:  http://www.programgood.net/2014/07/24/WHEALogger.aspx

[image: Screenshot of warning list]

[image: Screenshot of a warning]

Any thoughts?  Or just ignore :-)

- Fractal Design Define R4 Black Pearl Low Noise Mid Tower Case
- Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD3H LGA1150 ATX Motherboard
- Intel 4th Gen Core i7 4790K 4.0GHz 88W HD4600 8MB Quad Core CPU
- Crucial Ballistix Sport 16GB (2x8GB) 1600MHz CL9 DDR3 Memory
- Reeven Kelveros RC-1202 High Performance Quiet CPU Cooler
- FSP Raider 750W Quiet PSU, 80+ Bronze
- Samsung 840 PRO 256GB SSD High-Performance Solid State Drive
- Seagate ST4000DM000 4TB SATA 6Gbps 3.5in 5900RPM HDD
- LiteOn iHAS124 24x SATA DVD/CD Rewriter Optical Drive OEM
- Quiet PC Free Silver Warranty (2 years labour and parts)

Comment: It might help if you actually tell us what the warning says. You have Windows 8.0 or Windows 8.1 your question isn't clear about that particular fact.

Comment: Thanks - updated image to display a better error.  And that I'm using Win8.1 with all latest updates